# CTE returning wrong value in CASE EXIST

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want recover a boolean value if a specific neighbor exist in a city or not

**City**

```
City_Id | State_Id | CityName
1         6          São Paulo
2         22         São Paulo
3         26         São Paulo
```

**Neighbor**

```
Neighbor_Id | City_Id | NeighborName
```

**Query**

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT City.*
    FROM City
    WHERE (City.CityName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI) LIKE 'são paulo'
)
SELECT cte.*
    ,CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT Neighbor.City_Id 
            FROM Neighbor
            INNER JOIN cte ON Neighbor.City_Id = cte.city_id
            WHERE (Neighbor.NeighborName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI) LIKE 'ademar'
        )
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS F
FROM cte
```

**Result**

```
City_Id | State_Id | CityName   | f
1         6          São Paulo    1
2         22         São Paulo    1
3         26         São Paulo    1
```

**Error**

I know that in City_Id 2 don't exist any neighbor's in my table with this city id, so why return 1 in my `CASE EXISTS` when City Id = 2 ?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are running the queries against the same DB?

Comment: Yes, i've done some test to get sure like 
`1) select * from neighbor where city_id = 2` and don't exist a neighbor called `ademar` 
`2) select * from neighbor where city_id = 1` and exist a neighbor called `ademar`

Comment: Why not run an actual test

Comment: What result do you get if you try running `SELECT * FROM Neighbor where City_Id = 2 and (Neighbor.NeighborName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI) LIKE 'ademar'` ?

Comment: Nothing, don't return any row.

Comment: Try replacing the exists with a count to see if you are just having an exists issue: `CASE 
    WHEN (
            SELECT count(Neighbor.City_Id)
            FROM Neighbor
            INNER JOIN cte ON Neighbor.City_Id = cte.city_id
            WHERE (Neighbor.NeighborName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI) LIKE 'ademar'
        ) > 0
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is occurring because you are linking to the cte *separately* inside the sub-query - it isn't checking the value of neighbor against the cte for the specific row in the main query, but instead against the **whole** cte. Instead, try changing the expression for `F` to:

```
CASE 
WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT Neighbor.City_Id 
        FROM Neighbor
        WHERE Neighbor.City_Id = cte.city_id and
              (Neighbor.NeighborName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI) LIKE 'ademar'
    )
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS F
```

Comment: @Lucas_Santos: Are you sure? Compare the results of http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a83b9/1 with the results from http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a83b9/2

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see that you remove the `JOIN`, my mistake. This is only because my `JOIN` ? Works now.

Answer (score 1):

Why not run an actual test

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT City.*
    FROM City
    WHERE (City.CityName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI) LIKE 'são paulo'
)
            SELECT Neighbor.City_Id 
            FROM Neighbor
            INNER JOIN cte ON Neighbor.City_Id = cte.city_id
            WHERE (Neighbor.NeighborName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI) LIKE 'ademar'
```

Comment: And you are surprised that exists returns true?  It returns 3 rows and you think exists should be false?

Comment: @MarkBannister What would * matter.  It would not change the answer to exists.

Comment: So it does not return 2.  In your query you are not testing for 2.  You are testing for the condition in my answer.  You will get the same answer for every row.  That inner join cte is going back to the cte and is independent of you first reference to the cte.

Comment: But return the `City_Id` with values `1, 3, 3` and in my CTE query I put to return all cities called `São Paulo`, that returns 1, 2, 3. On my `SELECT` clause, in my `JOIN` I think that should search for 'ademar' neighbor in these 3 cities ID.

Comment: Understood. You wanna say that yhis is because my City_Id 3 returns 2 row for 'Ademar' neighbor.

Comment: Based on you first response it returns 3 rows.   Exits will return true if it returns 1 or more rows.  Your query is not what you think it is.

Comment: I thought that my query will get the first `City_id` and will match the `ademar` neighbor and return `1` or `0`if exist or not. After that will get the next `city_id` and do the same returning `1` or `0`.

Comment: Think about it.  My answer runs on its own.  I have already answered the question.  You have two independent references to the cte.